# Rotary encoders for automotive display

Tags: automotive, rotary-encoder

I'm looking into designing a display to show and adjust brake bias.  I'm planning to use a rotary encoder in order to select through menus.
Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time deciding which model of rotary encoder to use in order to withstand all mechanical forces present (g- foces, vibrations, etc) and also give a good mechanical feedback to the driver (helping the drive be sure that he actually rotated the encoder).
Taking a quick look, I've founds this model ([Mouser link](https://br.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/PEC11H-4120F-S0020?qs=7MVldsJ5Uaxh8cksqYCfvg%3D%3D)) PEC11H-4120F-S0020, I've choose it because it has a push button inside and appears to be robust, but I have no clue if it will work properly.
What should I look in order to determine if it will work as intendend?

Comment: Quality is more expensive. PEC11 is Bourns, EC11 is Alps, clone EC11 made in RPC costs 1/20 of original Alps, and so on.... Look for lifetime in specs (originals only).

Comment: You need to write yourself a specification. (1) Pulses per revolution. (2) Push-button. (3) Are (click) detents required. (4) Mechanical toughness. (5) Quadrature output? (Two pulses, 90 degrees apart.) (6) Shaft style (for knob). Et cetera ...

Comment: Alps were originally used in a lot of automotive applications. I would say read the specs, and buy some and test them in the proposed application **with** the proposed knob and support structure (since it may be hard to quantify the detent torque requirements and so on).